# How to integrate ant design and arangodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arangodb, feathersjs, antd

I'm gonna work with [ant design](https://ant.design/) as the frontend of a RESTful datadriven SPA that's gonna deal with CRUD operations, emails, reports, sessions, file uploads, authentication and authorization.

So I'm wondering if Foxx is gonna be enough as the backend technology? or do I need to use extra libraries, or a foxx client or a framework such as expressjs, sailsjs or feathersjs?

If someone could guide me through the process of setting up the fullstack, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Foxx is a MicroService offering, allowing you to host microservices running right inside the ArangoDB database.

What makes Foxx powerful is that it is able to publish these microservices as REST API endpoints, allowing your application to query them directly.

Additionally, Foxx can host static pages, so the HTML documents you need your client to download can also be served by Foxx.

When implementing your front end / dev stack framework, the best way to think of Foxx is that it can host both static web pages as well as REST API endpoints.

Foxx can also integrate with other systems from an authentication/authorisation point of view, including JWT.

Personally, I develop sites that integrate with Azure Active Directory OAuth, and unfortunately that is one OAuth provider Foxx cannot natively interact with. So what I do is host a Node.JS server in front of Foxx, and it just performs the OAuth security services and forwards calls (with appropriate auth data) to the Foxx back end.

For your implementation of the Ant Framework, just think of Foxx as a REST API that your framework can communicate with, and serve your HTML assets through Foxx static files.

Have a look at a ['ToDo' implementation in Foxx](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-aye-aye) to get some ideas on how you can use Foxx to host apps.

It's amazing how fast Foxx is with data queries.

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, I'll have a look at the example. And just in case, in a windows machine, do you know where do I have to add the static files for a foxx app?

Comment: Sure, have a look at [the Foxx documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Foxx/Assets.html). The easiest way is their second example, where you add a `files` section to your manifest for the Foxx service. If you look in the [ToDo example](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-aye-aye/blob/master/manifest.json) they use static file serving, and you can see how they populate their `files` section fo the `manifest.json` file.